# Data is not updated in database, using C#,WPF, Entity framework and Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, datagrid

This question is with reference to my old question here: [Primary key in datagrid is always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274469/primary-key-in-datagrid-is-always-zero)

In my previous question, i was working on pretty large database with many relationships, so i thought to give a try to and tested on this basic (very basic)
project.

What i did is i created simple basic wpf application. Added local database with only one table which has two columns.One is id column which is primary key and auto incremented.The other is simple varchar.I added that as data source and created grid from that data source.

here is my xaml:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="tablesViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Table}, CreateList=True}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource tablesViewSource}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="tablesDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="47,24,70,95" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding name}" Header="name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="221,266,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

</Grid>
```

The only two line of code is written by me. Rest is auto generated.Now i wanted to update my data from gridview, but the big problem is data is not updated.It keep adding zero.

I added entire cs file here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Table> GetTablesQuery(Database1Entities database1Entities)
    {
        System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<WpfApplication4.Table> tablesQuery = database1Entities.Tables;
        // Returns an ObjectQuery.
        return tablesQuery;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        WpfApplication4.Database1Entities database1Entities = new WpfApplication4.Database1Entities();
        // Load data into Tables. You can modify this code as needed.
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource tablesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("tablesViewSource")));
        System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<WpfApplication4.Table> tablesQuery = this.GetTablesQuery(database1Entities);
        tablesViewSource.Source = tablesQuery.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly);
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        var context = new WpfApplication4.Database1Entities();
       // Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();
        // db.SaveChanges();
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

}
`
[image]

I have started to doubt my basics. Please Help.

Comment: Where are you creating the Database1Entities  object, that is bound to your grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me (adjust variable names):

```
 using System.Data.Entity;

    private Database1Entities  _context = new Database1Entities (); 

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource tableViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("tableViewSource")));
        _context.Table.Load();
        tableViewSource.Source = _context.Table.Local;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        _context.SaveChanges();
        tableDataGrid.Items.Refresh(); 
    }
```

More info at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx

Comment: This worked....Although it is dataset and i am on EF...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547149.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var context = new WpfApplication4.Database1Entities();
        var table = context.Set<YourTable>();
        table.Add(new YourTable { Id = id, Name = "John Doe" });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```